# Sparse matrix (next element)

Tags: c#

I have to do a home project, but I can't do it with my current knowledge. I searched for it, but I haven't found any useful tips. Here is a sparse matrix, and I have to get the "Next elements" The next elements are the element who are the second in a 2d arrays column, if there is no second element, for that column the output is "-1" . In the output I need to write out the serial number of the element.

Here is the 2d array, the red numbers are the "serial numbers"[image: 1]
The output should be this : 8, -1, -1, 6, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1.

To clarify: if you scan left-to-right (and continue on the next row). Replace each value (greater than zero) with it's ordinal position (shown in red).  Then scan again (left-to-right, top-to-bottom) when you find any number (greater than zero), search down in that column. If there is another number (red) (greater than zero) in that column, print that (red) number. Otherwise print -1.

Second-pass, finding "Next elements".
[image: Second-pass, finding "Next elements"]
`0` finds 8, `1` finds nothing, `2` finds nothing, `3` finds 6, etc.

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Do you need help understanding the algorithm (how we got this answer from this data), the strategy (how to organize your program), or the coding itself?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, i just overthinked the algorytm of the program.

```
for(int i = 0; i < oszlop.Length; i++)
        {
            kov[i] = Array.IndexOf(oszlop, oszlop[i], i + 1);
        }
```

The "oszlop" array is an 1d array and contains the column indexes of the rare elements. If i got a rare element, i check if is there any other element with the same column index, if there is, i will save in the "kov" array, otherwise save "-1" in to the "kov" array.

Comment: Congrats! Thanks for sharing your solution with others.